# How to run multiple emulator and devices

Tags: android

I am working on an Android project. I want my app to launch in different emulator and devices simultaneously.

I have done this earlier by setting the "Run Configurations target" to "Always prompt to pick device". So every time I run my app, I am prompt to pick which emulator or device I would like to use.

Suddenly, the prompt stopped appearing. Thus, my app keeps running on a single emulator. I badly need it to run on different devices since I am working on a client and server app.

Comment: I guess you are using Android Studio?

Comment: Nope. I am using eclipse.

Comment: you can run app in emulator and then run in external device for checking to client and server app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Run" menu at the top, -> "Run Configurations" -> "Android Application" -> select your project -> Select the "Target" tab -> select "Always prompt to pick device" -> press "Run"

OR

If you have checked "Use same device for future launches" in chooser dialog, you must disconnect all devices (usb and emulators) and then click on "Run" again and uncheck the checkbox!

Comment: That is what I've been trying repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok GoTo Studio menu bar at the top and go to tools->android->AVD Manager then a new pop up would appear for new device. now create a new one and then again press run button. This time you would be prompt to select device but after selection you dont check the box saying 'Use same selection for future launches' so that your prompt box would not disappear again.

Answer (score 0):

> I want my app to launch in different emulator and devices simultaneously.

Here is the thing go to *Run -> Run Configuration -> Target tab and select **Launch on all Compatible devices/AVDs***

[image]

This setting will make your app run on all connected and compatible devices and emulators.